# What kind of ham radio license should I get?

Tags: united-states, legal, license, equipment-design

I have an interest in studying and researching how radio technology can be used in other fields of electronics. What kind of license should I look into so I can carry out some experiments or research?

My interest is ***Data propagation in Radio contexts***.

My intent is to experiment with Ham radio equipment to research viable Data networking and create equipment off of it.

I working at any band or VHF, UHF etc. that I fit and what I can do with once I have the documents in hand.

What I intended to do was co op existing radio hardware into designs or create external addons or chips to plug into your desktop or an existing sets. The reason why I ask this question is that I am fully aware of the idea that you need paper work to fully operate the transmitter or work in the bands.

If I don't intend to operate as a full blown "Station" but rather in a controlled environment, do I need an operational license or is there a specialty documentation that I can get to permit to me to use the equipment that I am co opting.

Radiation will be at times emitted but the bulk of the time the radiation will be confined. I will have to at times radiate but hopefully in low power modes. High power if permitted.

Comment: This is an amateur radio site, I guess people are going to suggest you get an amateur radio license.

Comment: The Internet is international, and this sort of thing varies by country, so stating in which country you live (assuming that's where you will conduct your experiments) will be of help.

Comment: What aspects of radio technology are you interested in?  It's quite a broad topic!  We can better tailor our answers if you give us some specifics or some examples of things that you might like to do with radio technology.  (Please edit your question rather than reply with a comment.)

Comment: By "data propagation" do you mean the physical propagation of (information-carrying) radio waves? Or do you mean matters of transferring digital data over radio? Or…?

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II can i have my question unlocked I edit the question.

Comment: @BenMadison I'm still not clear what you're asking. You say your intent is to experiment with ham radio equipment, so isn't it obvious that you should get a ham radio license?

Comment: @BenMadison I agree with the gentlemen who voted to close your question as too broad, etc. I've edited your question a little, but it's still leaving us all wondering what you really intend to do. Kindly edit your question with more details that answer the inquiries in these comments, and please tell us whether to want to use ELF, VLF, MF, HF, VHF, UHF, or microwave frequencies.

Comment: @BenMadison  Also, please keep in mind that we are all volunteers here with limited time; therefore, the more details you provide minimizes our own time **and helps us help you**. :-)

Comment: @BenMadison Sorry to nitpick, but could you kindly answer VE5EV's question above "*The Internet is international, and this sort of thing varies by country, so stating in which country you live (assuming that's where you will conduct your experiments) will be of help*".

Comment: @MikeWaters i added a tag, should that help?

Comment: I'd say this just barely meets the requirements for reopening. But seriously, add some information specifically about what you want to accomplish, because from what I see you want to send data over a radio on "any band", and the answer is _any_ ham radio license meets that requirement. To be a _good_ (and not just permissible) question, you should at least do some basic research into the kinds of licenses (there are only 3) and define a more specific and interesting problem.

Comment: Don't append "edit:" to the question: just straight up edit it so it reads well on its own. The edit history is available via a link at the bottom if people want to see it.

Comment: @PhilFrost-W8II Ok is this suficaint, have i cleared thimgs up or do i need to do more work.

Comment: Ham Radio is not broadcasting or a "cloud", and each transmission must have a Control Operator actually supervising to assure no inteference. Ham radio is non commercial.

Comment: I don't understand "documents in hand" and "papers".  In the US, paper documentation is not required, you only have to have your license in the FCC database.  Details like this are why you need to list what country you are operating from.   Without that, this question is still too broad.

Comment: Ben, by "If I don't intend to operate as a full blown 'Station' but rather in a controlled environment", do you mean that no RF will be radiated? If that's the case, then you probably don't need a license. **Can you please provide more details?** Are you going to use an antenna, or is all the RF going into a non-radiating dummy load?

Comment: Okay, thank you for clearing this up! :-)  However, as others have said here, you almost certainly cannot use this on ham radio, *either with or without a ham license*. Perhaps @BrianK1LI was correct, but I don't know the ISM rules. Maybe somebody else here does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to transmit a signal in the designated amateur bands youll need an appropriste level license.  Todays levels are Techncian, General then Amateur Extra. Get Gordon Wests study materisls, or even download a study app like ham radio test prep, and go from there.  Yiu may find you enhoy the hobby beyond your research work.

Comment: To clarify:  For what you want to do on UHF and VHF, all you need is a Technician license.  While studying for that license you will learn what higher level licenses are needed for privileges on other bands.  But a Technician license is all you need based on your description.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to conduct your research on one or more of the "ISM" bands, set aside for industrial, scientific and medical research without a license. Though there are some regional variations, most of the bands can be used worldwide.

Comment: It seems to me that the legality of this was discussed here before. [Here are several ISM threads](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=ISM%20) that you might find useful.

Comment: Now that we know more about what the OP is doing, perhaps your answer is a good one, Brian.

Answer (score 1):

Ham Radio is not broadcasting or a "cloud", and each transmission must have a Control Operator actually supervising to assure no inteference.  Ham radio is non-commercial.

Comment: Let's see if he answers my new comment. Perhaps he is not radiating.

Comment: Also, welcome to hamSE! :-)